# SQL Select everything after numeric character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following text in column:

```
ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD
```

I would like to extract everything after number and before `ML`

**Expected output:**

```
100 MG PL/2 ML
```

I tried `RIGHT` with `PATINDEX` but it is displaying the whole string after numeric data like following:

```
Select RIGHT(col, PATINDEX('%[^A-Z] %', col))
From table
```

Output obtained:

```
100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD
```

Can anyone suggest me how to extract this data?

Comment: You only did the first part which is finding the starting point. Now you need to use left or substring and charindex to get the stopping point.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. @SeanLange

Comment: Is there a specific format to this string? How do you identify the end of your expected return value? Does the expected return also have an expected format? ie will the last 5 characters always be a space followed by 4 characters?

Comment: @Shawn No, there is no standard format but it will be space followed by some alpha characters. I think we can use something like this `% [^A-Z]%`

Comment: "after number" is not the correct description for your example. Do you mean starting from the first number? Does it have to be just numbers until next space or is X3Z also a valid starting point?

Comment: @JamesZ I have got the solution for this problem from below answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT('ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD',CHARINDEX('ML', 'ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD') + 2),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%','ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD'),LEN('ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD'))
```

-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LEFT(col,CHARINDEX('ML', col) + 2),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',col),LEN(col))
                                     from table
```

Although, you state in your question you want everything from "before" 'ML' and your expected output has 'ML' in it

Comment: I have added sample expected output in bold. I am sorry if my explanation was misleading.

Comment: Thank you very much @precose6. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @SamitaPradhan Is "ML" guaranteed to be in the string? If so, that makes it simpler to identify, but less flexible if your input changes to include multiple measurements (which is what I'm assuming you are extracting). Regardless, for future readers, this is very exclusive to this particular problem.

Comment: @Shawn for this query "ML" is guaranteed, but I am writing another query for different set of data and your solution is helping me to extract data from multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one as well

```
declare @str varchar(50)
set @str='ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABC D'

select @str
select PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@str),charindex(' ML ',@str),len(@str)
select substring(@str,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@str),charindex(' ML ',@str)-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',@str)+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4c1b/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( col varchar(50) ) ;

INSERT INTO t1 (col)
VALUES 
      ( 'ABC XYZ 100 MG PL/2 ML ABCD' ) 
    , ( 'ABC XYZ 99.9 MG PL/2.5 ML ABCD' )
    , ( 'ABCXYZ 10 mg pl/2 l abcdefghijklmn' )
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
/* 
    This extracts a substring from col, beginning at the 1st digit
    after a space, and ending at the length of the whole string minus
    the position of the last space minus the position of the 1st digit
    after a space (the first throwaway substring). 
*/

SELECT SUBSTRING( col, 
                  PATINDEX('% [^A-Z]%', col) /* ID 1st digit after space */
                  , LEN(col) /* length of full string */
                    - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(col)) /* identify the last space */
                    - PATINDEX('% [^A-Z]%', col)+1 /* subtract the first throwaway chars also. */
       ) AS ss
FROM t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4c1b/1/0)**:

```
|                 ss |
|--------------------|
|     100 MG PL/2 ML |
|  99.9 MG PL/2.5 ML |
|       10 mg pl/2 l |
```

What this won't account for though is if your final set of characters has a space in it. But if that's an issue, the final `CHARINDEX()` can be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @Shawn.

Comment: This will also pull `2 g` out of `abc 2 g abcdef`.